# Stubbing Swift Extension for Unit testing

Tags: ios, unit-testing, alamofire, stub, stubbing

I am looking into unit-testing a Swift class which uses *Alamofire* network library. What I want to do is to stub the *download* function of the library's *Manager* class with some simple behaviours that does not use the filesystem so that I can isolate my test cases from the filesystem.

The main problem that I found is that the download function is written as an extension and therefore cannot be overridden. (See Notes in [extension documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html))

This case should apply to any other cases that would like to stub third-party library's functions defined with extensions. Any suggestions are welcome.